# G-Brief 2 verändern

Tags: german, dinbrief

I used the g-brief document class. Now I would like to move the footer a little further down and shorten the line under the return address. Is this possible?

I'm still new to LaTeX, maybe someone can help me.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: This is an English speaking site. Please translate your question.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE! Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: To elaborate on Zarko's comment: please provide the full LaTeX code needed to create the document in your screenshot, that will make it much easier for potential answerers to implement the changes you ask about.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

You can move the footer down by changing the height of the  text area using

`\setlength\textheight{<length>}` (from 178.9 mm to 190 mm in this example)

To shorten the line below the return address, choose a suitable length with the command `\newcommand{\returnlinelength}{<number (without units)>}` (70 mm in the example)

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\def\filedate{2019/03/14}
\def\fileversion{4.0.3}

\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,latin9]{g-brief}

% ***************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength\textheight{195mm} % default 178.88mm <<<<<
\newcommand{\returnlinelength}{70} % line lenght = 70mm <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ps@firstpage}
{\put( -9, -22.10){\line(1,0){85}}}{\put( -2, -22.10){\line(1,0){\returnlinelength}}} 
{}{}
\makeatother
% *****************************************

\lochermarke
\faltmarken
\fenstermarken
\trennlinien
%% \klassisch

\Name                {Otto Raffzahn}
\Strasse             {Wiesenacker 25a}
\Zusatz              {}
\RetourAdresse       {}
\Ort                 {D-99533 Weitewelt}
\Land                {}

\Telefon             {+49\ 000\ 00000}
\Telefax             {+49\ 000\ 00000}
\Telex               {}
\HTTP                {http://www.example.com}
\EMail               {raffzahn@example.com}

\Bank                {Bankhaus Skrupellos \& Co.}
\BLZ                 {000.000.00}
\Konto               {000.000.000}

\Unterschrift        {Otto Raffzahn}

\Postvermerk         {E I N S C H R E I B E N}
\Adresse             {Frau\\
                      Else Mittellos\\
                      Finsterweg 12\\
                      \\
                      D-93456 Tiefeschlucht
                      }

\Betreff             {Zahlung Ihrer Miete}

\Datum               {\today}
\IhrZeichen          {}
\IhrSchreiben        {}
\MeinZeichen         {OR}

\Anrede              {Sehr geehrte Frau Mittellos,}
\Gruss               {Mit freundlichen Gr\"u\ss{}en}{1cm}

\Anlagen             {}
\Verteiler           {}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

seit der siebten Mieterh\"ohung im laufenden Jahr konnte ich keinen
Zahlungseingang von Ihnen mehr verbuchen. Ich bitte Sie Ihren
Verpflichtungen schnellstens nachzukommen, da ich mich sonst gezwungen sehe,
Ihre Miete ein weiteres mal anzuheben.

\end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```